# Handle Multiple Timezones in MySQL

Tags: mysql, optimization, timezone

I am using **MySQL** database for my Application. I am using **Java (with Spring)** for my web development and **Apache Tomcat** for Application Server. In my application there are multiple users with different **Timezons**. Now suppose I am calculating total login time for users.

     I am providing SQL Fiddle link [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e018f/1) for necessary DDL and DML queries. In that I have also written select query for count total login time for every user. In that users with userIds 3 and 4 are not still logged-Out, so I am using NOW() for counting total logged in time. But they are from **different timezones**. And I am storing all times in MYSQL with **GMT-0**. So will it give me wrong logged time for userId 3 and 4 or not? If wrong, what is solution for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So will it give me wrong logged time for userId 3 and 4 or not? If wrong, what is solution for it?

If you actually record the value with GMT+0 won't give you the wrong answer. It doesn't matter what the local time is for the user - all you're interested in is how much time has elapsed between login and logout.

Indeed, using the user's local time zone would make this much harder - you'd end up having to take account of daylight saving time. So for example, suppose you were logging my interactions on October 26th 2014. I might have a *local* login time of 1:45am and a *local* logout time of 1:05am, which sounds messed up - until you realize that the login time was when daylight saving time was in effect. If you just record the UTC time (GMT+0) you'd record 00:45 and 01:05, leaving the obvious difference of 20 minutes.

Basically, when you are trying to record *points in time* you might want to record the time zone of the user so you can tell them what they saw at the time... but you should record the date/time itself in UTC for easy manipulation (e.g. translation into another time zone). You should *very* rarely record the local date/time; it's useful for recurring events (e.g. "2pm local time every week) but for individual points in time it's just a bad idea.

Note that recording the UTC time is *not* the same as recording the local time on the server; you should try to make sure that the server's time zone is completely irrelevant to the application's behaviour... aside from anything else, that means nothing bad will happen if you have multiple servers in different time zones. Given that [`NOW()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) uses the system local time zone, that *could* give the wrong answer - it would be a good idea to try to use a function which uses UTC (e.g. use `UTC_TIMESTAMP`), or set the "current time zone" in MySQL to UTC. (You claim to already be storing the dates in GMT-0, but it's not clear how you expect that to happen if you're using `NOW()`, unless you *are* setting the time zone to UTC.)

Comment: Hi @Jon Skeet.. Thanks for your quick answer but Should I use **NOW()** if it's using System's local timezone (which may be differ from **GMT-0**)? If no, how can how can I calculate time? Not possible?

Comment: @VishalZanzrukia: As per my answer, I'd suggest using `UTC_TIMESTAMP`. Or set the time zone for the *connection* to UTC.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you are doing it correctly. im sure it will give the time of the server that is hosting MYSQL.

Comment: Using the local time of the server is a bad idea due to DST changes - and the possibility that you'll want to have multiple servers in different time zones. The OP claims to be storing times with GMT-0, but it's hard to see how that fits in with using `NOW()`.